# Upgrade a Database table to add a new column

Tags: sql

I need to convert an existing db table to a new db table which adds a new column.
I have the following sql code which set the default value of this column to be -1.

```
// Insert new column for holding appWidgetIds
db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE favorites " +
   "ADD COLUMN appWidgetId INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT -1;");
```

But how can i set the default value of the column to increment one by one for each row?

Comment: Which SQL? Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, ... ?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your DBMS. **MySQL** uses [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html):

```
ALTER TABLE favorites ADD COLUMN appWidgetId INTEGER
  NOT NULL DEFAULT -1 AUTO_INCREMENT
```

**PostgreSQL** uses [`CREATE SEQUENCE`](http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=626300):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE favorites_seq;
ALTER TABLE favorites ADD COLUMN appWidgetId INTEGER
  NOT NULL DEFAULT -1 nextval('favorites_seq')
```

**SQL Server** uses [`IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196(SQL.80).aspx):

```
ALTER TABLE favorites ADD COLUMN appWidgetId INTEGER
  IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL DEFAULT -1
```

As a side note, I don't know why you're setting your default as -1. Why would you make your integers signed if they will always be positive? You should make the default 0 for efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on which DBMS you're using. For MySQL, you can use:

```
ALTER TABLE x ADD COLUMN y INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT -1 AUTO_INCREMENT
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html

Comment: Not familiar with MySQL+AUTO_INCREMENT - how does he control which records get which values?

Comment: Rows will be assigned incrementing values for y in order of their insertion. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 0):

Are values auto-incremented for new rows AFTER your conversion too? If not, you could do 3 steps:

1. ALTER the table with NULLable column
2. UPDATE the new column with whatever rules you have
3. ALTER again to set NOT NULL.